# 2010 Workflow Designed in Sharepoint Designer 2013 Fails on Start

Tags: designer-workflow

Using Designer 2013 I created a 2010 WF (d/t having certain capabilities that a 2013 WF does not) and deployed it.

It is set to start manually. I went to the list added a new item and started the WF.

However, I get the error below:

[image]

I am not using a System Account so that's not the issue.Can anyone assist in what's causing the issue?

Comment: I think we'll need to see your workflow

Comment: It just logs to history nothing else. Please advise.

Comment: Can you create a new workflow from scratch and test? Seems very weird a simple 2010 workflow gets cancelled on start.

Comment: Can you check the uls logs to see the exactt error .